# Can expectation of a random variable be a random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose I have, $$ X = 1$$ with probability $p$ and $$X=0$$ otherwise.
Now, if $p$, in turn, is a random variable (for example, let's say it takes a value from 0 to 1 uniformly at random), what is $\Bbb E[X]$?
Is it just $p$ or $\Bbb E[p]$?

I took some examples (with a dice) and that makes me think that it is $\Bbb E[p]$. Also, as the expectation is constant, I think it cannot be just $p$. But, I am not sure if my logic is correct. I tried looking into this, but the answers I see either involve a lot of measure theory (which I don't know) or are not exactly related to my question.

I apologize if the question is not clear, I can give any extra details that you consider necessary.

Edit: I am not sure if this is the right way to edit and continue a question with a follow-up, but I have an additional question now.

For the example mentioned here, can I instead write $$X=1$$ with probability $E[p]$ and $$X= 0$$ otherwise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $E(X)$ is a number.  Your example shows that the distribution of $X$ may be complicated.

Comment: @herbsteinberg, if $E(X)$ is a number (a constant) then I guess it cannot be $p$ since $p$ is a random variable. 
But, is $E(X) = E(p)$? (Would the property $E(E(X)) = E(X)$ be useful here?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case we have $X\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$ where $p$ is a random variable. We have \begin{align*}
\mathbb E(X|p)&= p\\
\mathbb E(X) &= \mathbb E(\mathbb E(X|p)) = \mathbb E(p)
\end{align*} which is a constant, not a random variable.

Comment: Thank You! This makes sense!

Comment: I have added a follow-up question. Can you let me know if I hypothesis is correct? Thank you so much.

Comment: not really correct, if you say $X=1$ with probability $\mathbb E(p)$ then the success probability becomes a constant instead of having a random success probability

Comment: I see; Thanks again!